# Vue - run method for every v-for item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I loop through days in a calendar via v-for:

`<ul><li v-for="day in daysInMonth"></li></ul>`

Over in Firebase, I have events stored. Each event has a date property:

```
eVeNtKeY
  date: 12/7/17
```

Now, each day won't have an event but I need to get an event count for each day. I downloaded all the event for the month via Firebase call and have it saved in the Vue `data` as an array `thisMonthsEvent`.

```
data: {
  thisMonthsEvents: [bunch of firebase data],
  currentMonth: number
}
```

Is there a way to run a method for every repetition of the `v-for`? In my thinking, I could do something like this:

```
    computed: {
        eventsByDay () {
          return this.thisMonthsEvents.filter(function (event) {
            return event.date === this.currentMonth + '-' + Somehow get the day from loop + '-2017'
});
        }
      }
```

Comment: Add current day as an argument for method `eventsByDay (day)` - and use it there; also pass it inside `v-for` loop: `<li v-for="day in daysInMonth">{{ eventsByDay (day) }}</li>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a method instead of a computed property and call the method directly in the `v-for` loop, passing in the `day` variable:

```
methods: {
  getEventsByDay(day) {
    return this.thisMonthsEvents.filter(function (event) {
      return event.date === this.currentMonth + '-' + day + '-2017'
    });
  }
}
```

```
<li v-for="day in daysInMonth">
  {{ getEventsByDay(day) }}
</li>
```

Comment: Perfect! The only thing I had to add was `.length` to get the count.

Comment: @thanksd when I try this, I get `Property or method "myMethod" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`. This template is nested several levels deep in other templates.

Comment: Hey @KirkRoss, I don't define a `myMethod` method in my example, so if you are referencing a method by that name but haven't defined it in that template's component's `methods` object, you will get that error.