# Fire function in template according to v-for index value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use Vue 2 in my project.
I have this html  generated in template:

```
    <expandable-item v-for="(name, index) in names" :key="index" >
        <span v-if="index==0"> {{ initData(name) }}</span>
    </expandable-item>
```

When expandable-item starts to generate an index equal to zero(index=0) I need
to fire this function initData(name).

My question is how to trigger this function initData when the index is zero?

**UPDATE:**

I need initadata method to be called only once but it looks like it called multiple times and cause to browser memory overflow. I assume that it happens because of the virtual DOM.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935058/vue-run-method-for-every-v-for-item

Comment: Not a lot of information in your question, but I agree that the link in the first comment should help.  You may also want to modify ```initData(index, name)```, test for ```if (index === 0)```, and only run your data initialization logic then.

Comment: What does `initData` actually do? There's probably a better place to call that (e.g., from a component method).

Comment: @tony19 the function makes http call to api

Comment: That really should be done from a component method. If you need it to be based off `names`, use a watcher that calls the API.

Comment: is `names`  initialized synchronously?  b/c I think the cleaner way to do this is to prepare names with the async gotten first element, and just let the template observe that change. I think it's worthwhile to think of the template as declarative